# TSC with allowJs compiles its own compiled JS outside rootDir

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have a project with a file structure like this:

```
package.json
webpack.config.json
tsconfig.json
src/
assets/
node_modules/
compiled/
etc/
```

All my source code (a mixture of `.js` and `.ts` files) is in `src` and all my compiled output should go in `compiled`. My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./compiled/",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I run TSC to my surprise it also tries to compile its own compiled output in the `compiled` dir, even though this is outside the `rootDir`, and since `allowJs` is enabled it will pretty much endlessly re-compile its own emitted JS, creating `compiled/compiled/compiled/compiled/` dirs.

I thought that `rootDir` would limit the files to be compiled to the root dir. I could add "compiled" to `exclude` but there's also quite a few other folders outside the `rootDir` that contain JS (other build tools and such), all of which are being undesirably compiled and output with `allowJs` enabled... must I explicitly exclude everything or is there no way to explicitly limit the compiler input to the `src` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `--rootDir` doesn't do what you think it does - it allows more control over the output directory structure (to more or less enforce it to match the input one rather than be smart about it).

Documentation about the parameter (from `tsconfig.json` schema):

> Specifies the root directory of input files. Use to control the output
>   directory structure with --outDir.

Pull Request description that implements that option: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2772

> The current behavior of the compiler when using --outDir is to
>   duplicate the input structure in the output under the value of
>   --outDir. the root of the input is computed as the longest common path of all source (.ts and not .d.ts) files. so an input of
>   FolderA\FolderB\1.ts and FolderA\FolderB\2.ts would result in
>   computing the commonSourceRoot to FolderA\FolderB. now if a new file
>   FolderA\3.ts is added to the input, the commonSourceRoot will pop out
>   to FolderA.

One more good explanation and example: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/287

Comment: That makes sense, I definitely did not understand the purpose of `rootDir`. So is there no way using `tsconfig.json` to limit the compiler input to a directory path?

Comment: @Aaron It appears that you can only `exclude` directories or alternatively include specific individual files using `files`. The `tsconfig.json` file can also be placed in a subfolder other than the root.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's been awhile so I guess it wasn't supported at the time but [`tsconfig.json` now has a `include` configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md) which can accept glob-like patterns, like `"include": [ "./src/**/*" ]`